# How to use OPENROWSET with MSOLEDBSQL driver?

Tags: sql-server

MSOLEDBSQL driver is installed in my system. I am using the below syntax to connect to a database in a different SQL Server using OPENROWSET:

(in example I am trying to read from the same system)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'MSOLEDBSQL'
    , 'Server=<Computer Name>;Database=<Database Name>;TrustServerCertificate=True;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;'
    , 'SELECT * FROM [database name].[dbo].[table name];'
    ) c;
```

I am getting the below error:

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned
>   message "Client unable to establish connection".
>
> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned
>   message "SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an
>   authority that is not trusted. ".
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot initialize the data source
>   object of OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)".

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: The middle message in that list is your key: `OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. "`  This error can occur for a number of reasons, but the core is that (1) you are using encrypted communications, and (2) the certificate you are using does not meet the security criteria SQL Server requires. Likely, this was a local, self-issued certificate, which SQL Server is reluctant to trust, but more detail on the certs and settings would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although, the [MSOLEDBSQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server) recommends `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` to enable new encryption and certificate validation behavior, I don't think the stricter validation will allow a self-signed certificate, trusted or not.

Try removing the `Authentication` keyword and instead specify `Trusted_Connection=Yes` if you are using a self-signed cert.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'MSOLEDBSQL'
    , 'Server=<Computer Name>;Database=<Database Name>;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
    , 'SELECT * FROM [database name].[dbo].[table name];'
    ) c;
```

Comment: This is what I get after executing the below script: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: @kish, the query works for me. What SQL version? Are you running the query as a sysadmin role member?

Comment: I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB3194720) - 12.0.4232.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1). The user running the query has public and sysadmin roles. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @kish, I just successfully tested with SQL 2014 SP3 (doubt if the SP matters). Run a trace on the remote server to capture `error_reported` event. Maybe that will provide more error details. For troubleshooting, you could also try query like `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;` to rule out a problem with the query itself.

Comment: I checked the servername, thats correct in the query. I am still getting the same error. Is it because SSMS is 32 bit in my system and I have the 64 bit version of MSOLEDBSQL installed in my system? Tried installing 32 bit driver in my system, looks like not supported.

Comment: @kish, I meant for you to try `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` in the `OPENROWSET` query to see if you get the same error. I wouldn't expect SSMS or other client components to be a factor.